# How to Remove This Bathroom Faucet Spout

Tags: plumbing, faucet, removal, plumbing-fixture, bathroom-fixtures

I am replacing the faucet in my guest bathroom but I am having a difficult time removing the center spout of a widespread setup (I think it is an old Moen). I have loosened the nut underneath the counter but the T just spins which leads me to believe the spout should spin off but it doesn't. How should go about getting this off?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I figured it out. The T underneath actual just pulls off and then the nut spins off then the spout can be pulled up through the hole. As an aside it is amazing how easy the new faucets are to install.

Comment: What do you mean "just pulls off" Surely it was secured somehow? I'm having a similar problem with a brass t-connector that won't pull or unscrew. There appears to be a nut like in your picture and it won't budge.

Answer (score 0):

The brass you see accepts the water supply hose.  It should come out by itself.  And the nut above it actually secures the faucet to the sink from below.  That is all.
When installing that faucet, that nut undeneath goes on first all the way to the top securing the faucet.

The brass fitting goes afterwards.
It is rather an interesting set up.  Not sure what to make of it.

Hope that helps.
Take care.

Comment: Isn't this what the OP figured out and posted as an answer 6 years ago?

Comment: @FreeMan, I can not respond with one gesture or a word otherwise I would have just answered it with an emoticon like this.  :-)